# How can I detect click of AutocompleteSupportFragment in Android

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have implemented AutocompleteSupportFragment to search for [places](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) in Android. When we click on the autocompleteFragment in the layout, it opens the places search fragment as overlay.

I need to detect that click on its search box that opens the overlay. If I override the click listener on the view, then the original click flow doesn't work. Can anyone suggest how to detect the click without causing issues to the click flow? Thanks.

```
private lateinit var autocompleteFragment: AutocompleteSupportFragment
...
autocompleteFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment)
                as AutocompleteSupportFragment
```